# SQLITE table joining with group

Tags: join, subquery, sqlite

```
            MESSAGE TABLE                                       USERS
msg_id | msg_to | msg_from | msg_body | msg_date            user_id  | user_name
  1       1          2         hi      22/1/14                 2          jeff
  2       2          1        hello    22/1/14                 3          john                 
  3       1          2        howdy    22/1/14                 4          james
  4       2          1       nothing   22/1/14
  5       3          1        yes      22/1/14
  6       1          3         maybe   22/1/14
  7       4          1         no      22/1/14
  8       1          4         cool    22/1/14
  9       4          1         hot      22/1/14
```

*note that user 1 does not have any data in the users table.

I am having an issue getting all the messages uniquely in a stream based on who it was sent from. That is I want the last message that is exchanged between each user who communicates with user `1`. I am trying to populate a list that should should the last message exchanged, so the list would be similar to this

```
          MESSAGE LISTING
     name      |         last_message
     jeff                   nothing 
      john                  maybe
     james                   hot
```

Last messages exchanged between user 1 and the other users at all times, user 1 does not have data saved in the users table but I have access to his `user_id` if needed in query.
I tried doing a `JOIN` with the users table `ON msg_from = user_id`  but this only returns the last message from one user, so the last message exchanged between user 1 and user 2 is `howdy` instead of nothing based on this sample. I am not quite sure how to tune this query to represent the correct dataset that is needed, any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: "Last" message? How can you tell which message is last when all the dates are identical?

Comment: hey there @ypercube, by "Last message" I mean the who ever spoke last, the message may be sent on the same day however the messages table does have an auto increment column.

Comment: And we should guess that? Please add this auto increment column that defines the order you want. I'd expect a timestamp column but if auto increment you use, that's ok.

Comment: Point taken there, a timestamp column would be useful for ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery computes, for each user in `USERS`, the latest `msg_id` value:

```
SELECT *
FROM MessageTable
WHERE msg_id IN (SELECT (SELECT msg_id
                         FROM MessageTable
                         WHERE msg_to   = Users.user_id
                            OR msg_from = Users.user_id
                         ORDER BY msg_id DESC    -- or by a timestamp
                         LIMIT 1)
                 FROM Users)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will give it a go, but that was the problem with the subquery I tried initially I was not sure how to limit the message results per user. Will report after I have tried it.

Comment: Worked, much thanks for the help. I was missing the appropriate subquery to limit the messages. I also needed to grab the user_pic for each but I figured it out with a bit of creativity, not the most efficient way however but it works for now.